# How to run two update statements with one button?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update

I'm trying to update my stock value if the user enters to add or delete.

My code runs after adding and deleting but is updated with the added value.

My update only runs the SQL. I tried creating another `preparedstatement` but it didn't work. The code is given below and I am using java Netbeans.

```
private void Update_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if (txt_add.getText().equals("") && txt_delete.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Stock value");
    } else {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=InventoryTrackdb";
        String un = "sa";
        String pass = "123";
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, pass);

            int pv = Integer.parseInt((Table_stock.getValueAt(Table_stock.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString()));
            int value;
            int value1;
            if (txt_add.getText().equals("")) {
                value = 0;
            } else {
                value = Integer.parseInt(txt_add.getText());
            }
            if (txt_delete.getText().equals("")) {
                value1 = 0;
            } else {
                value1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_delete.getText());
            }
            int fv = pv + value;
            int fv1 = pv - value1;
            if (fv1 < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Negative Stock");
                clear_text();
            }

            else {

                String sql = "Update  Add_item set Stock = '" + fv + "'  where Itemcode = '" + txt_id.getText()
                        + "' and Itemname = '" + txt_name.getText() + "' ";

                String sql1 = "Update  Add_item set Stock = '" + fv1 + "'  where Itemcode = '" + txt_id.getText()
                        + "' and Itemname = '" + txt_name.getText() + "' ";

                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                pst.executeUpdate();

                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                pst.executeUpdate();

                update_table();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated Successfully");
                clear_text();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main_stock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the image of the page:

[image: Here is the image of the page]

Comment: Your JDBC code looks, at a first glance, to be correct.  Have you checked that the database connection is working? Do you get any exceptions?  Also,  even though you are using a prepared statement, you concatenate together the query, thereby bypassing the whole purpose.  Look into binding parameters into a prepared statement in Java.

Comment: Yeah, that's the *whole* point of using prepared statements. They help sanitizing input, and avoiding bad results [(as here)](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't throw any exception and the database connection is also correct.I will look into binding parameter.Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you certain that the updates are actually targeting any records?  This is the next thing I would check.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I add some value in add stock then it updates the table by adding the value and shows updated successfully but when i enter value in delete stock it shows updated successfully but doesnt update the value.The value remains same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid syntax error or SQL Injection, In your case it's better also to use **batch** like this :

```
String sql = "Update  Add_item set Stock = ?  where Itemcode = ? and Itemname = ?";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);) {

    pstmt.setString(1, fv);
    pstmt.setString(2, txt_id.getText());
    pstmt.addBatch();//First Batch

    pstmt.setString(1, fv1);
    pstmt.setString(2, txt_id.getText());
    pstmt.addBatch();//Second batch

    int[] result = pstmt.executeBatch();//Submits both batch of commands to the database

}
```